# Opening a webpage using tabs and intent fails?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need three tabs, each of which opens a different webpage.
My code uses tabhost and three separate activities. 
The app works the first time, but the webpages fail to open 
on second trial. How can I fix this?

MyTabActivity.java

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("Tab1",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class)));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("Tab2",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.invoice))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab2Activity.class)));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("Tab3",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.products))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tab3Activity.class)));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
 }
```

Tab1Activity.java

```
 public class Tab1Activity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.yahoo.com" );
    startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a WebView in the xml for each of the Activity and load the url in that?

Answer (score 0):

TabActivity has been deprecated in API Level 13. A more modern way to achieve what you are trying to do would be using [ActionBar navigation tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs). Use a [WebViewFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html) for each web page tab.

Answer (score 0):

As you have all separated activities you can achieve it using TabActivity as well.

Start intent in TabHost using

```
intent= new Intent().setClass(this, yourFirstactivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```